# How to enable emacs keybindings on macos globally?

Tags: emacs, key-binding, macos-highsierra

I have a macbook pro 2015 that runs on High Sierra. I want to use emacs key-bindings or shortcuts for regular things like copying and pasting. For instance, I want to use "M-w" to copy instead of "Command-C".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [Cocoa Text System](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Introduction/Introduction.html) is pretty customizable, you should be able to add your own set of bindings within ~/Library/KeyBindings. You could see [Jacob Rus' comprehensive guide](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/site/cocoa-text.html) on the subject if you wish to learn more about how macOS makes text happen on your screen, or you can follow these TL;DR steps:

1. Download the [Emacs keybindings](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/site/KeyBindings/Emacs%20Opt%20Bindings.dict) compiled by J. Rus
2. Rename the file to DefaultKeyBinding.dict(if there is an existing file of the same name, rename it to DefaultKeyBinding.dict.ORIG)
3. Put the file into the ~/Library/KeyBindings folder(if this folder doesn't exist, create it)

**EDIT:** As of Aug 3, 2022, the second and third links have broken and its unclear if there are mirrors out there. I found what appears to be the source for the article here: https://github.com/jrus/cocoa-text-system

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in Terminal and Firefox on El-Capitan, any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, the links are broken now!

Comment: you could use hammerspoon or karabiner elements to make such keybindings.